# Fully Connect to a Remote Desktop using Batch

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop

I want to make a simple program to help connect to a Remote Desktop, this is what I got till now:

```
 @echo off
 echo Connect Program
 echo Enter IP of computer:
 set /p ip=
 echo Enter Username
 set /p user=
 echo Enter Pass
 set /p pass=
```

Now I just want the code where I fill the variables %ip%, %user%, %pass%.
Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc.exe) doesn't allow you to provide the credentials from the command line. Running `mstsc /?` from a command prompt shows the available switches:

> MSTSC [] [/v:] [/admin] [/f[ullscreen]] [/w: /h:] [/public] | [/span] [/multimon] [/edit "connection file"] [/restrictedAdmin] [/prompt] [/shadow: [/control] [/noConsentPrompt]]
>
> "connection file" -- Specifies the name of an .RDP file for the connection.
>
> /v: -- Specifies the remote computer to which you want to connect.
>
> /admin -- Connects you to the session for administering a server.
>
> /f -- Starts Remote Desktop in full-screen mode.
>
> /w: -- Specifies the width of the Remote Desktop window.
>
> /h: -- Specifies the height of the Remote Desktop window.
>
> /public -- Runs Remote Desktop in public mode.
>
> /span -- Matches the remote desktop width and height with the local virtual desktop, spanning across multiple monitors, if necessary. To span across monitors, the monitors must be arranged to form a rectangle.
>
> /multimon -- Configures the Remote Desktop Services session monitor layout to be identical to the current client-side configuration.
>
> /edit -- Opens the specified .RDP connection file for editing.
>
> /restrictedAdmin -- Connects you to the remote PC or server in Restricted Administration mode. In this mode, credentials won’t be sent to the remote PC or server, which can protect you if you connect to a PC that has been compromised. However, connections made from the remote PC might not be authenticated by other PCs and servers, which might impact app functionality and compatibility. Implies /admin.
>
> /prompt -- Prompts you for your credentials when you connect to the remote PC or server.
>
> /shadow: -- Specifies the sessionID you wish to view.
>
> /control -- Allows control of the session.
>
> /noConsentPrompt -- Allows shadowing without user consent.

This indicates that the only way to ask for the user credentials when launching is to either have them stored in the .RDP file in advance or to prompt the user at run time using `/prompt`.

Comment: You can use `CMDKEY` in a batch file to add the credentials to Credential manager.

Comment: @Squashman: Which would be having them stored, wouldn't it (albeit not in the .RDP file)? Also, can you add the credentials for a MSTSC session without admin privileges?

Comment: The credential manager is a per user setting. A user does not need any elevation privileges to add credentials to the credential manager.  CMDKEY is just used to automate it.  Otherwise you can just use the GUI to do it as well.

Comment: @Squashman: Thanks - I was unaware of the ability to add credentials without elevation from a command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I derived from [this post](https://znil.net/index.php?title=Batch_RDP_Verbindung_starten_mit_Benutzername_und_Passwort). First, an entry for the login credentials is created. Second, the RDP connection is established. Third, the entry containing the credentials is deleted. I've been using this on Win7 and Win10 so far.

I call this script from the [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) password manager which passes the parameters to the script.

**Usage example:**

```
rdp.bat "my.host.name.de" "port" "username" "password"
```

**rdp.bat**

```
:: RDP connection without password prompt ------------
:: %1 = hostname
:: %2 = port
:: %3 = username
:: %4 = password
:: ---------------------------------------------------
cmdkey /add:"%~1" /user:"%~3" /pass:"%~4"
start /wait mstsc /v:"%~1:%~2"
cmdkey /delete:"%~1"
```

> **Note:** 
>   If the script running in the background is closed before the RDP session has ended, the entry containing the login credentials will not be deleted. Only use this approach if you know what you are doing. **Do not use this e.g. on a public computer, as your login information might be exposed!!**